# Symfony2.3 many to many form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, many-to-many

I'm having some issues getting many to many to work on my form.

My form is laid out in the following way:

User (FOSUserBundle)
Member (custom class)
Region (custom class)

The member form is a subform of the user form, and the region form is a subform of the member form.

Firstly, the error I'm getting is:

> Neither the property "region" nor one of the methods "setRegion()", "_*set()" or "*_call()" exist and have public access in class "Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Member".

This happens when I submit the form and it hits the:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Here is all the relevant code:

Member.orm.yml

```
Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Member:
type:  entity
table: member
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    security_question:
        type: string
        length: 255
    security_answer:
        type: string
        length: 255
----- SNIP -----
manyToMany:
    region:
        targetEntity: Region
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
```

Entity\Member.php

```
<?php

namespace Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Member
 */
class Member
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $region;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->region = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add region
     *
     * @param \Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region $region
     * @return Member
     */
    public function addRegion(\Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region $region)
    {
        $this->region[] = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove region
     *
     * @param \Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region $region
     */
    public function removeRegion(\Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region $region)
    {
        $this->region->removeElement($region);
    }

    /**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->region;
    }
```

Form\MemberType.php

```
<?php
namespace Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class MemberType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('region', new RegionType())
```

Region.orm.yml

```
Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region:
type:  entity
table: region
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    region:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

Entity\Region.php

```
<?php

namespace Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Region
 */
class Region
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $region;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set region
     *
     * @param string $region
     * @return Region
     */
    public function setRegion($region)
    {
        $this->region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get region
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRegion()
    {
        return $this->region;
    }
}
```

Form\RegionType.php

```
<?php
namespace Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegionType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('region', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region',
                'property' => 'region',
                'empty_data' => null,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
             ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Netsite\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\Region',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'RegionType';
    }
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to replace in MemberType.php:

```
$builder->add('region', new RegionType())
```

with

```
$builder->add('region', 'entity',
              array(
                  'class' => 'YourBundle:Region',
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'expanded' => true,
                  'required' => true|false,
                  'property' => 'region',
                  'label' => 'your.label',
                  'error_bubbling' => true,
              )
)
```

This will render an area with checkboxes labeled Region::region (confusing naming scheme btw. should be just 'name'). Multiple checkmarks will be reflected with multiple M2M entries.